# не работают js скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Привет всем!* Помогите с js. Написал пару функций на скрипте

```js
'use strict';
function main() {
     alert("This!")
}

read.onclick = function() {
 window.open('http://google.com');
};

pade.onclick = function() {
 this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

Сначала кодил в онлайн редакторах кода, где все работало просто отлично. После я связал с html и перенес код на локальный сайт:

```
<head>
  <style>
    #pade {
            transition-property: background-color;
            transition-duration: 2s;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="read">Follow</button>
<button id="pade">No more</button>
<.body>
```

После чего ни один код не работал, вставлял код в  и в файл app.js. В консолях хрома и фаерфокса пишет ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `let read = document.getElementById('read');`. Не видно, чтобы сам элемнт был в переменную помещён.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, странно , что онлайн редактор типа этого http://jsfiddle.net/ смог без проблем его скомпилировать

Comment: Ну получилось-то?

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at'' - при нажатии не реагирует

Comment: А вы где и как вставляете js код? Скорее всего, во время работы js кода страница еще не загрузилась и элемента в DOM еще нету.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko. Сначала в отдельный файл залил, потом в тег <script>. Не знаю, поможет это или нет, когда файл открываю js на рабочем столе тоже вылетает и пишет ошибку простые скрипты типа alert идут на изи

Comment: Ничего странного) В jsFiddle не включен строгий режим. Из-за чего под все id создаются одноименные переменные, ссылающиеся на HTML-объекты... Такое можно использовать только для быстрых тестов, но не в реальном коде (что и делает `use strict` - убивая потенциальную ошибку на начальном этапе). А по поводу script, нужно заставить его загрузиться после HTML. Для этого или тег `<script>` перенести в конец разметки, или добавить атрибут `<script src="..." defer>` или завернуть весь код в `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ /* сюда */ })`

Comment: P.s. если use strict включен в одном скрипте - этот режим распространяется на все скрипты на странице, которые в теории могут сломаться) Хорошо бы его включать внутри функции `(function(){ "use strict"; /* куда пойдет основнй код */ })();`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME. Думаю, строгий режим здесь непричем). Подозреваю, что проблема в синтаксисе. `"use scrict"` - уже убрал из исходника, а результат все тот же. Нашел решение на англоязычной Stack: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845033/how-to-change-button-color-onclick-using-javascript-only`. Пожалуйста, напишите ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я смог закрыть вопрос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузер берет все элементы, у которых есть `id` и создает одноименные глобальные переменные, которые доступны в коде, когда не включен строгий режим. Эту фишку можно использовать, если нужно быстро тестить фрагмент кода, но не нужно включать в реальный код, потому что могут быть сюрпризы:

```js
box.textContent = "Работает!";

(function() {
  let box = document.createElement('div');
  
  /* ... много-много кода... */

  /* Вы уже давно забыли про объявленный box */
  (function() {
    box.textContent = "Оппа, текст попал не туда, куда планировалось"; // (*1)
  })();
})();
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

**(*1)** Интерпретатор JS натыкается на переменную `box` и ищет её внутри текущей функции. Её там нет → идет проверять родительскую "скобку" / функцию. Находит там объявленный `let box` и работает с ним. Уже не доходит до глобального box.

Такое редко может случиться, но всё равно должно стать привычкой: всегда и везде объявлять переменные и получать элементы по `id`:

```js
let box = "test";

(function() {  
  let box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.textContent = "Ура! Нет ошибки.";
})();
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

А режим `"use strict";` просто помогает вылавливать такие ошибки на начальном этапе, выдавая ошибку из-за любой необъявленной переменной.

Ваш пример:

```js
"use strict";

function main() { // Вы здесь просто ОБЪЯВИЛИ функцию.
  alert("This!");
}

main(); // А это её вызов, через () скобки

document.getElementById('read').onclick = function() {
  console.log('http://google.com');
};

id('pade').onclick = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};

/***/

function id(str) {
  // Если лень каждый раз писать getEleляляля, можно сделать такую функцию
  return document.getElementById(str);
}
```

```css
#pade {
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button id="read">Follow</button>
<button id="pade">No more</button>
```